# RMSE result and interpretation

Tags: python, time-series, predict

hello I am new in the field of forcasting time series, I am working on a project to predict the number of visitors hourly from sensors .
I found an RMSE equal to 76 for a variable in values ranging from 0 minimum to 400 maximum
can this rmse be considered a good result or not and how i can interpret it.

```
          RMSE          MAE
Sarima 76.094180    46.066214
Prophet 76.247419   46.120543
XGBoost 76.405984   46.193548
```

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

if RMSE less then better. You have max value 400 and RMSE 76. I will explain you how you can get it:

> For one predict: Real value = 380 Predicted value = 304 RMSE =
> sqrt(sqr(380 - 304)) = 76
>
> For two predicts: 1: real value = 360    predicted value = 286
>
> 2: real value = 300    predicted value = 378
>
> RMSE = sqrt(((360 - 286) * (360 - 286) + (300-378) * (300-378)) / 2) =
> 76,03

I think you have to big error. You must tune you hyperparameters or select new features.